# rosconsole command line utility not honoring ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT

Tags: ros, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have set up my shells to have a custom [ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Console_Output_Formatting)

```
export ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT='${time:%T.%f}[${severity}] ${node}/${logger}: ${message}'
```

When I run or launch nodes, they have the desired format:

```
22:45:20.180207[ INFO] /test_node/ros.test: Test node message
```

However, if I use the rosconsole command line utility,

```
rosconsole echo -l info
```

I get the default format that does not have the time in it:

```
[ INFO  ] [/test_node]: Test node message
```

How do I make the output of the rosconsole command line utility show in the desired format?

I know I can pass option -v to show verbose messages, but I don't want all of that. Honestly, I am having trouble finding documentation for the command line utility. Everything I search for brings me to the library and it's not on the wiki's utility page.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396508/rosconsole-command-line-utility-not-honoring-rosconsole_format/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2022-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How do I make the output of the rosconsole command line utility show in the desired format?

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/3f8eca4a1f13996b33c03a5c4ee3a69fb0db3668/clients/rospy/src/rospy/rosconsole.py), I don't believe you can.

That script uses a `rospy.Subscriber` to subscribe to the `/rosout` topic topic ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/3f8eca4a1f13996b33c03a5c4ee3a69fb0db3668/clients/rospy/src/rospy/rosconsole.py#L168)), and uses a relatively simple callback to print incoming messages in a fixed format ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/3f8eca4a1f13996b33c03a5c4ee3a69fb0db3668/clients/rospy/src/rospy/rosconsole.py#L181-L190)):

> ```
> def _print(self, msg):
> ```

```
    print('[ {} ] [\033[1m{}\033[21m]: {}'.format(
        self._level_string_map[msg.level], msg.name, msg.msg))
```

> ```
>     if self._verbose:
> ```

```
        stamp_sec = msg.header.stamp.to_sec()
        stamp_tz = datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp_sec, tzlocal())
```

> ```
>         print('          [{} ({:.6f})] [{}]: {}:{}'.format(
> ```

```
            stamp_tz, stamp_sec, msg.function, msg.file, msg.line))
```

You would have to change the script to get it to print in any other way.

If you do, and there isn't already a PR open, it would be nice to add this feature to the script and submit it for inclusion in `rospy`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0